# Extracting elements in a string based on keyword w/ Bash

Tags: regex, bash

I'm automating a hardware task and one of the tools I'm using outputs a list of serial devices to connect to. The format is as follows:

Available device (a) : /dev/stuff

Available device (b) : /dev/watermelon

Available device (c) : /dev/stuff

I need to find the line that "watermelon" occurs on and then extract the letter inside the parentheses. So in this case, it would be "b". However, the order is not guaranteed to be preserved (that's why I have to search by "watermelon").

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very easily with `sed` and a *backreference*, e.g.

```
$ sed -n '/watermelon/s/^[^(]*(\([^)]*\).*$/\1/p' file
b
```

Where

- `sed -n` suppress normal printing of lines,
- `/watermalon/` match the line with watermelon,
- `s/find/replace/` - the normal substitute option

  - find `^[^(]*(\([^)]*\).*$` what is in parens and save as 1st reference
  - replace `\1` with what was saved as first referent
- `p` print the result.

If you must use bash, then you can do it with `[[ ]]` and the `=~` operator and *parameter expansion with substring removal*, e.g.

```
while read -r line; do 
    [[ $line =~ watermelon ]] && { tmp="${line#*\(}"; echo "${tmp%)*}"; }
done < file
```

**output**

```
b
```